# "Pausing" a running calculation in R and resuming it on different day

Tags: r

Let's say I have a huge calculation in R. For some reason (badly optimized code, big calculations, slow computer, etc) this calculation will take several days.

I want to split up a calculation in R over multiple days (with possible shutting down of the machine), resuming from where I left off last time I booted up R. How can I do this?

For an example, lets say I want to calculate the mean of 100 Million. And this mean is calculated manually by summing over each value and dividing over 100000000. And my computer is limited to 1 Million computations a day a day without overheating, I have to shut off my computer and restart at the next day. Taking approx 100 days total.

Here's the code of my example:

```
total <- 0
for (k in 1:10^8) total <- total + k
print(total/1000^8)
```

What I was thinking was output a textfile, giving the current index and current total. Then resume based on the information in the text file. Something like:

```
total <- totalFromText
start <- lastIndexFromText
end <- start + 10^6
for (k in start:end) total <- total + k
```

Is there any better way to do this? Is there anyway to pause a running calculation in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause an R process within R itself with, for instance, [Sys.sleep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.sleep.html), or you can pause an R process at the OS level. On Linux, you can look for the pid of the R process, then run `kill -STOP <pid>` to pause the process and `kill -CONT <pid>` to resume it. You can find the full documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html).

But in your situation, I think that the best solution is to create checkpoints within your code: break the code into smaller chunks and save outputs, objects, or state of calculation after each chunk has run.

For long-running calculations, checkpoints are a good practice, whether you want to kill the process or not: it is a guaranty that if anything happens before the computation is complete (computer crash, or any other cause of failure), you don't have to re-start from the beginning, possibly loosing large amounts of computing time.

HPC clusters have great checkpoint mechanisms that can be set outside of the running processes themselves because they are built to conduct very large computations which often run for days, because failures can happen, and because they often have schedulers limiting how long each user can run computations for on any given day.

As you are running this on your own machine however, you have to implement these within R.

One option could be to save the output of each chunk of your code as an R object in a `.rds` file with `saveRDS()`. Other options are to use `save()` or `save.image()` to save all your R objects or all of your workspace respectively in a `.RData` file.

You can then launch the chunks one by one (if they are in different scripts for instance) based on how long you want to have an R process running. Or you can launch the whole thing and kill it when you need to. On Linux, a clean way to kill the R process is to use `SIGTERM` or `kill -15 <pid>`.

The next day, when you want to restart your computation, you can read your last result, stored in an `.rds` file with `readRDS` (or similar if you chose to save your output in a different way) and start the next chunk.

As for the particular example you gave: break your loop into several smaller loops the size of which being determined by how many checkpoints you want to have.